# 720p streaming support for appInventor?

Tags: android, video-streaming, app-inventor

I've been trying to build a 720p streaming video player in AppInventor, and cannot figure out how to get the video player to do anything remotely like 720p, nor can I figure out how to get it to listen-to / attach -to a UDP video stream on the WIFI.

The doc for the App Inventor video player component is here:
http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/reference/components/media.html#VideoPlayer

The doc for the supported video sizes in android is here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Reading these docs, I'm left with the impression that

1. Android only supports 480 x 360 H.264 video (I'm fine with H.264, but not 480x360) in it's native widgets.
2. App Inventor does not support Streaming.

Has your mileage varied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Actually there isn't a spec for what encoding sizes or if hardware acceleration is required of devices so depends on the manufacturer and model. There is however some minimal set of requirements set by Google in their [Android Compatibility Definition Document](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html) if a manufacturer wants Android Market.
2. App Inventor is really interesting Google Labs project and realize that it is a 'Labs' project so trying build a streaming player with it might be a bit out of scope. I think its more for the hobbyist and education folk (Lego Mindstorm modules) than anything else. Since App Inventor just wraps the Android Framework, you would be better off going straight to the Android SDK and doing it there.

My recommendation, if you are trying to do a streaming app, use Java and the Android SDK.

Comment: Yup, my next move is to pull up the entire SDK.  Thought it would be an interesting exercise to put app builder through it's paces.  I love the idea, just not enough control for my tastes.

Answer (score 0):

> App Inventor does not support Streaming.

App Inventor supports the "Activity Starter Component" which can be used to start the Android Video Player application, which will play an RTSP stream.

I used the following properties on the Activity Starter component to start an rtsp stream:

Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
DataUri: rtsp://a.sample.domain/somestream.sdp